# How can I define a type to present a stream which can provide integers, but also may fail?

Tags: scala, types, stream

Suppose I want to define a "NumberLoader", which will load integers from another place by demand, so I can give it a type:

```
type NumberLoader = Stream[Integer]
```

But it may throw errors when loading (say, it loads integers via network from another computer), so there should be some `NetworkError` in the type.

Finally, I defined it as:

```
type NumberLoader = Stream[Either[NetworkError, Integer]]
```

If seems to work, but I feel it a little strange. Is it a good one?

Comment: Seems right to me. You can also use `Stream[Future[Int]]` or `Stream[Try[Int]]` (or scalaz validation types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to represent

```
a Stream of something which can be either a NetworkError or an Integer
  Stream[                          Either[  NetworkError,      Integer]]
```

so the type looks appropriate and well-suited.

You can alternatively use `Future` or `Try` in place of `Either`, but you would lose the flexibility of specifying the kind of exception you expect, as both `Future` and `Try` failures hold a generic `Throwable`.